# Using DXA to test XPM infrastructure

Tags: dxa, experience-manager

We're setting up the infrastructure to support Experience Manager, and our plan is to use the Digital Experience Manager to verify that the basic functionality is working, without having to depend on our own implementation for this. So far I have listed a few simple tests:

1. Modify component. Check that Update Preview works.
2. Add a new component presentation
3. Add a new page

I'd like to have this better focussed on the infrastructure elements that may be misconfigured, and choosing tests that verify specific aspects.

Which infrastructure elements should I be covering, and what tests would take care of this?

Comment: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3C70F892-69F4-4FEE-922D-39F1AFEBD539

Answer (score 4):

I like seeing DXA being used for System Testing purposes; we're doing that ourselves (within SDL Web DevOps) too nowadays!

I think you've come up with a good set of test cases already.

In particular the first is an excellent one: Session Preview ("Update Preview") is sort of the ultimate system test for XPM; there's so many things that can go wrong (misconfiguration) with it, that it's always a delight to see it working properly! :-)

The other two test cases are useful to test XPM Page Types and Content Type. Also verify that Pages and Components are created in the expected location in the BluePrint (we've discovered XPM bugs in this area using DXA System Testing in the past).

Another test case (a step earlier in the process) could be to check that XPM markup is generated on a "Staging" website (i.e. a CD Environment with Preview Capability), but not on a "Live" website (i.e. A CD Environment without Preview Capability).